# java regex match is null

Tags: java, regex, match

I am trying to find a particular pattern but also exclude certain patterns. For some reason, my regex is not working in my program, but it works with an online regex tester. What is the problem?

Here is the online test: [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/oI2jF9/1)

Here is the java test:

```
private void TestRegex() {

    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("Every Witch Way 3x19 New Witch Order (2015)");
    strings.add("The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon Episode dated 22 January 2015 (2015)");
    strings.add("October Gale (2014)");
    strings.add("Kung Pow: Enter the Fist (2002)");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((?!.*(\\d*x\\d*|Episode dated)).*) \\((\\d*)\\)$");

    for (String s : strings) {

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {

            Log.d("TAG1", s);
            for (int j=0; j<matcher.groupCount(); j++) {
                Log.d("TAG2", "Match " + j + ": " + matcher.group(j));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the output from my test:

```
... D/TAG1﹕ October Gale (2014)
... D/TAG2﹕ Match 0: October Gale (2014)
... D/TAG2﹕ Match 1: October Gale
... D/TAG2﹕ Match 2: null
... D/TAG1﹕ Kung Pow: Enter the Fist (2002)
... D/TAG2﹕ Match 0: Kung Pow: Enter the Fist (2002)
... D/TAG2﹕ Match 1: Kung Pow: Enter the Fist
... D/TAG2﹕ Match 2: null
```

Why is match 2 null? In the online matcher it matches correctly for both.

explanation for the regex string:

I wanted to match all strings with the format `Movie Title (Year)` and ignore all strings which contain the string `\d*x\d*` (examples: `1x01`, `2x05`, `3x11`) or that contain the string `Episode dated` because those strings refer to TV show episodes, not movies, which I am trying to separate. I also need to match the Movie title as well as the year.

Comment: ah, yes. good catch but I don't think that is the problem. I'll fix my question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is mainly with this `j<matcher.groupCount()` condition. You have three groups but this condition will print only the two excluding the group 0. By turning `<` to `<=` will help you to print the last group also.

```
for (int j=0; j<=matcher.groupCount(); j++) {
                Log.d("TAG2", "Match " + j + ": " + matcher.group(j));
```

> Why is match 2 null?

It's because the capturing group present inside the negative lookahead assertion. Like other answerer said, turning that capturing group to non-capturing group won't create an extra group.

```
Group 0 = Prints the entire match
Group 1 = Prints the characters which are present inside the group index 1.
Group 2 = Prints the characters which are present inside group index 2. Likewise it goes on.
```

Comment: Wow, that's really weird. I would have thought that would have caused an index out of range exception, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
^((?!.*(?:\d*x\d*|Episode dated)).*) \((\d*)\)$

 ^^     ^^                               ^^


Group1   Group2                          Group3
```

`Group2` is the null group you are getting.In the regex101.com your year `2002` is getting matched by `group 3`.Make second group non capturing.

When your string matches because of negative lookahead `Group2` cannot be there.So it will be null.

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/oI2jF9/2